# gulp-less set global var

Tags: gulp, gulp-less

I use `lessc` to compile my file in command line before, and it contains couple options like this:

```bash
lessc --global-var=ENV=dev --global-var=version=10 --no-color $FileName$
```

Now I want to use **gulp-less** to compile it, but how can I pass my options to it?

Below is part of my codes:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('less', function(){
  return gulp.src('css/index.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to solve it, just set `globalVars` inside `less()` like:

```js
gulp.task('less', function(){
  return gulp.src(['css/*.less', 'css/*/*.less'], {base: 'css/'})
    .pipe(less({
      globalVars:{
        ENV: "dev",
        version: 10
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```